# Issue with 'Evaluate Expression' in Android Studio Debugging for Flutter code: Displaying '<optimized out>'

Tags: flutter, android-studio, debugging

When debugging Flutter code in Android Studio, I am encountering an issue where I cannot successfully use the 'evaluate expression' feature. Instead of providing the expected result, it displays `<optimized out>` as the output for any expression I attempt to evaluate. 
 Please find the screenshot below.

[image]